# how to verify a pop up appeared for few seconds using C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

How to verify the text or title of a pop up visible for few seconds using C# selenium webdriver. which appears under a certain conditions.

This is the code I have:

```
<div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage" style="z-index: 100001; position: fixed; padding: 5px; margin: 0px; width: 350px; 
top: 10px; text-align: center; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: medium none; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: 
default; right: 10px; opacity: 0; border-radius: 10px;">
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and C# code. Current one doesn't have text or title and tag doesn't even close.

Comment: In java we do WebdriverWait wait = new WebdriverWait(driver,10000); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());   I am sure there must be something in C# which can help you. just google it